# Reading Binary data from a Serial Port

Tags: c#, .net, binary, serial-port

I previously have been reading NMEA data from a GPS via a serial port using C#. Now I'm doing something similar, but instead of GPS from a serial. I'm attempting to read a KISS Statement from a TNC. I'm using this event handler.

```
comport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

Here is port_DataReceived.

```
        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = comport.ReadExisting();

        sBuffer = data;

        try
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate { ProcessBuffer(sBuffer); }));
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the method is being called several times per statement. So the ProcessBuffer method is being called with only a partial statment. How can I read the whole statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serial communication allows to break data flow into messages by using timeout. But following 
[KISS TNC](http://www.ka9q.net/papers/kiss.html) there no such functionality is presented in this protocol.

> Each frame is both preceded and
>   followed by a special FEND (Frame End)
>   character, analogous to an HDLC flag.
>   No CRC or checksum is provided. In
>   addition, no RS-232C handshaking
>   signals are employed.

My suggestion is to break data stream into messages by decoding Frame End characters.

Answer (score 0):

volody is right: You have to look for the FEND (0xC0) and only try to process the buffer when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

See this

[Serial 101](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/a709d698-5099-4e37-9e10-f66ff22cdd1e)

Comment: That article is fantastic, but I'm struggling with when to apply the encoding he is writing about. I have attempted it when defining the serial port like so: 
        private SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();
        comport.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

Adding it there gives me an invalid token error. Next to my read statement. 

            comport.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
            string data = comport.ReadExisting();

It gives me an error: cannot be access with an instance reference. I don't know exactly where to use this. Could you help me out?

Comment: in vb

    Dim sp As New IO.Ports.SerialPort
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'other serial port settings
        'before open
        sp.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")
    End Sub